# WPF - Customized Window Style and Use Image to Minimize, Maximize and Close Button Triggered by Different Data

Tags: wpf, image, button, background, datatrigger

I want to use customized window style and use image to Minimize, Maximize, Normal and Close Button.

Now I hope when WindowState is Maximized, show Maximize image (from resource).

When WindowState is Normal, show Normal image (from resource).

Xaml is below:

```
<Button Height="42" Width="42" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Click="Button_Maximize_Click">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/AccuPick3D;component/Image/Maximize.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/AccuPick3D;component/Image/Restore.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}">Maximize or Restore</ToolTip>
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>
```

Button_Maximize_Click event:

```
private void Button_Maximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = (this.WindowState != WindowState.Maximized) ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal;
        }
```

But it doesn't show image whatever I click button or not.

[image]

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the `Background` property directly. Instead you should specify the default value in a `Style` setter:

```
<Button Height="42" Width="42" BorderBrush="Transparent" Click="Button_Maximize_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/AccuPick3D;component/Image/Maximize.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/AccuPick3D;component/Image/Restore.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}">Maximize or Restore</ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

The reason for this is that local property sets take precedence over style setters as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

You should also make sure that your bindings work. Unless you have set the `DataContext` to `this`, you should set the `RelativeSource` property of the bindings like this to bind to a property of the parent window:

```
Binding="{Binding WindowState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Comment: Great! It's exact what I want, now I more understand how WPF Dependency Property works, Thanks!